# Getting request.getHeader("Authorization") as null while hitting api from browser but not in postman

Tags: java, servlets

Here is my filter which I have written in java that will intercept all the incoming http request.

When I am trying to get or print `request.getHeader("Authorization")`, it is giving me `null` but if I am hitting same request from postman, I am getting the value of it.

```
package com.web.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter{
    
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws 
        IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String header=request.getHeader("Authorization");
                
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {              
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Comment: That proves that your browser is not sending that header. Why do you expect that to happen?

Comment: Browser is sending the header, I have verified that.

Comment: Any help will be really appreciated, just to highlight I am running both front end and backend in localhost but at different ports

Answer (score 0):

i guess in browser your request could be not cors (crosserver). Case frontend and backend running on same domain - localhost. When you are using Postman, your request is cross domain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but can you explain or tell what changes I need to make so that it could work from browser as well

Comment: just to update, I am hitting the api from Angular application

Comment: Thanks, this issue is resolved, actually for pre-flight request it is coming as null but after that it is having correct value